# I'm in a loop with Winforms Testbox LostFocus and Textbox GotFocus

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I try to do some formatting and my formatting results are working fine. The issues is it it's a loop with Textbox LostFocus and GotFocus event. So in debug it's jumping to each other and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The conversion of the NUMBERS are working fine, it's just the loop. So it starts when I click with mouse on the Textbox : txtBase2

1. it enters the txtBase2_GotFocus event line 8
2. then line 9 is executed
3. then it jumps to txtBase2_Lostfocus method to line 3
4. then back to txtBase2_GotFocus method to lin8 again.

these above 4 steps remains in loop... and it doesn't stop
What am I doing wrong? Or what is the thing that I don't see?

ps: the conversion is done for Amount values.

the whole idea is:

- when the user types amounts in the Textbox and he leaves the textbox it should format like: 1.245,12 (with thousand separator)
- when the user leaves the textbox and there are amounts/digits then the textbox numbers should be formatted like 1245,12 (without thousand separator)

THE CONVERSION OF FORMATTING WORKS FINE BUT IT's IN LOOP WITH THESE 2 EVENTS!!!!!!

winforms, C#, .NET 4.5

please advice?

```
     protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        txtBase2.LostFocus += txtBase2_LostFocus;
        txtBase2.GotFocus += txtBase2_GotFocus;

    }



 private void txtBase2_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Line 1:/ /when leaving the TEXTBOX
        Line 2: //input: 1234,56
        Line 3: double toDouble = Convert.ToDouble(txtBase2.Text);
        Line 4: string jj = toDouble.ToString("n", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("NL-be"));
        //output: 1.234,56
        Line 5: txtBase2.Text = jj.ToString();
    }

    private void txtBase2_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Line 6: //when Entering (get in) the TEXTBOX
        Line 7: //input 1.234,56
        Line 8: CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("NL-be");
        Line 9: string decimalFormatted = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBase2.Text, ci).ToString();
        //Output 1234,56
        Line 10: txtBase2.Text = decimalFormatted;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a side-effect of you setting the Control.Text property within the handlers.

You should really be using the [Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx) and [Leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) events instead.

The documentation for [Control.GotFocus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx) has this to say:

> > Typically, the GotFocus and LostFocus events are only used when updating UICues or when writing custom controls. Instead the Enter and Leave events should be used for all controls except the Form class, which uses the Activated and Deactivate events.

Do you still get the issue if you use `Enter` and `Leave` instead?

Also, do you get the issue if you comment out the code where you set Control.Text?

Comment: I changed to ENTER and LEAVE events and only ENTER event is fired when I click with mouse on the Textbox. but LEAVE event doesn't fires.  

And I've removed the Control.Text code in both function, no difference...still don't know why it's in a LOOP.?

Comment: ok found the problem: instead of txtBase2.text in line3 and line10 I have used (sender as TextBox).Text, and I also used then LEAVE and ENTER functions now it works fine... Thanks Matthew.. but why does it work if I do: (sender as TextBox).Text. if I do txtBase2.text, it's not working in becomes in loop.

Comment: That's really weird - I can't explain it!

Answer (score 1):

I can no longer test this, running Windows 8 on my machines, but this code is dangerous.  It is *very* likely to throw exceptions at a very vulnerable point in the Windows message loop.  A problem on a 64-bit operating system (Vista and Win7) with your EXE project's Platform target set to x86.  You can verify that theory by looking in the Output window for "first chance" exception notifications.  And diagnose it with Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.  Or by changing the platform target to AnyCPU.

Another strong indicator that GotFocus and LostFocus have cooties is looking at the visible events in the designer.  Select the textbox and click the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.  Note how both GotFocus and LostFocus are **not** listed there.  The Enter and Leave events are the alternatives.

You will need to do this differently.  First and foremost, you **must** use Decimal.TryParse() so you can see the conversion failed without an exception.  This is an expected failure, the user could have easily left the text box empty or typed a string that isn't a number.  You of course don't want your program to crash when that happens.

Secondly, use the Validating event instead of the Leave or LostFocus event.  You can set e.Cancel = true to prevent a focus change and force the user to enter a valid number.  Use the ErrorProvider component to display a warning when the Text is not convertable.  If you are doing this right then you don't need the Enter event anymore.  Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15207773/17034) for a NumberBox control that does this.