# C# Reading Textbox ignoring characters

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

Hi everyone i have a key down event as follows

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
{
    var amount = textBox1.Text;
    var total = label3.Text;
    decimal damount = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(amount), 2);
    decimal dtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(total);
    var ntotal = dtotal - damount;
    var ndue = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(ntotal), 2);
    var ntotal1 = Convert.ToString(ndue);
    if (ndue <= 0)
    {
        panel4.Show();
        label4.Text = ntotal1;
    }
    else
    {
        label3.Text = ntotal1;
    }
    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

this event works like i want it but here is my question how do i when reading the textbox1.text ignore character such as c or a , since the keydown requires c it messes with my decimal conversion any suggestions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a textbox accept only digits and formats numbers with commas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163564/how-to-make-a-textbox-accept-only-digits-and-formats-numbers-with-commas)

Comment: no not a duplicate im trying to figure out how to ignore character in the text box

Comment: Copy your comment and paste it in the textbox.  Now you got two problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `e.SuppressKeyPress = true; e.Handled = true;` to your handler when you want to prevent the key press from going forward.

As an aside, your if statement is equivalent to `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)`, since it will never be equal to both `C` and `Enter`.

Comment: i do see now that my plan will not work thank your for you input

Answer (score 1):

A while back I wrote a short post about restricting user input into TextBoxes, which is available here ([Restricting allowed characters in TextBox](http://satalketo.com/2010/08/restrict-characters-entered-into-textbox/)) but one thing that I realised that it didn't handle was users pasting text that contains those characters into the TextBox for that the following may be of use to you ([Stopping someone from pasting into a TextBox](http://satalketo.com/2010/08/stop-someone-from-pasting-into-a-textbox/)). Both of the posts were written in VB.NET but the code is simple enough that you shouldn't have any issues moving the code over to C#.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The first link "Restricting allowed characters in TextBox" is not working.  Would be helpful to include a code snippet here.