# Disable spacekey textbox in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, space

I have textbox that need to allow only numbers, delete and backsapce. This code works for this, but its allowing space key even though I disabled it. I'm not sure what is missing here.

```
public class NumberTextBox : TextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows only numbers, delete, backspace keys
    /// </summary>
    public NumberTextBox()
    {
        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnKeyDown);
    }

    private bool IsNumberKey(Key inKey)
    {
        if (inKey < Key.D0 || inKey > Key.D9)
        {
            if (inKey < Key.NumPad0 || inKey > Key.NumPad9)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool IsActionKey(Key inKey)
    {
        return inKey == Key.Delete || inKey == Key.Back;
    }

    private bool IsSpaceKey(Key inKey)
    {
        if (inKey == Key.Space)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !IsNumberKey(e.Key) && !IsActionKey(e.Key) && IsSpaceKey(e.Key);
    }

}
```

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125470/c-sharp-reading-textbox-ignoring-characters  
Just make sure the input key is a digit, otherwise suppress it.

Comment: To fix this code, you should use: `e.Handled = (!IsNumberKey(e.Key) && !IsActionKey(e.Key)) || IsSpaceKey(e.Key);`

Comment: @SepehrM, thanks for your comment. I have added your suggestion which did not work, but I changed it to PreviewKeyDown instead KeyDown, so its working now.

     PreviewKeyDown += new  KeyEventHandler(OnKeyDown);

Answer (score 1):

From the [microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    bool allowSpace = false;

    // Restricts the entry of characters to digits (including hex), the negative sign,
    // the decimal point, and editing keystrokes (backspace).
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);

        NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
        string decimalSeparator = numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        string groupSeparator = numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator;
        string negativeSign = numberFormatInfo.NegativeSign;

        string keyInput = e.KeyChar.ToString();

        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            // Digits are OK
        }
        else if (keyInput.Equals(decimalSeparator) || keyInput.Equals(groupSeparator) ||
         keyInput.Equals(negativeSign))
        {
            // Decimal separator is OK
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '\b')
        {
            // Backspace key is OK
        }
        //    else if ((ModifierKeys & (Keys.Control | Keys.Alt)) != 0)
        //    {
        //     // Let the edit control handle control and alt key combinations
        //    }
        else if (this.allowSpace && e.KeyChar == ' ')
        {

        }
        else
        {
            // Swallow this invalid key and beep
            e.Handled = true;
            //    MessageBeep();
        }
    }

    public int IntValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Int32.Parse(this.Text);
        }
    }

    public decimal DecimalValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Decimal.Parse(this.Text);
        }
    }

    public bool AllowSpace
    {
        set
        {
            this.allowSpace = value;
        }

        get
        {
            return this.allowSpace;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry this for winforms, I need it for wpf.

Comment: The concept is the same, all you need is to correctly handle `e.Handled` @Santosh