# how to restrict a user to enter only single character i.e "Y" and "N" using a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to restrict a user to enter a single character, either "Y" or "N" and nothing apart from that. I tried the below regular expression, but it does not work:

**^(Y|N){1}$**

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
      Regex r = new Regex(@"^(Y|N){1}$");
        r.IsMatch(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

The regex expression that I used is not working. How can I restrict a user to enter a single character which can only be "Y" or "N"

Comment: Why not just do: `if (textBox1.Text == "Y" || textbox1.Text == "N")`?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but would a simple checkbox make more sense?

Comment: Why are you saying it not working....I just ran this... and IsMatch was set to true....

Regex r = new Regex(@"^(Y|N){1}$");
var isMatch = r.IsMatch("Y");

Perhaps you are missing the code that follows...

Comment: With uppercase and lowercase: Regex r = new Regex(@"^[ynYN]{1}$");

Comment: but how can I restrict the user to enter only one character?

Comment: This will help you restrict it... http://stackoverflow.com/a/16125508/1706578

Comment: Take a look at my answer @Yash

Comment: @Yash, are you still there?

Comment: You can use "^[Y|N|y|n]$" to make sure they are required to enter Y or N (or lowercase y or n)

Answer (score 3):

You can try following regex:
^[YN]$

it will just match the characters Y and N, you can also add more characters if need arises.

Comment: Don't forget to use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Comment: Anyway, I think the hardest part here is how you control the textbox rather than the regex part. That's why I would rather use the `TextChanged` event.

Comment: @Andrew, I think OP just asked for the regex which would restrict the input to "Y" and "N", but yes, using IgnoreCase is a better as it would handle more real scenarios if input is coming from user.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to forego the regular expression, you can do one of the following:

- Must be a single character (any single character):

  ```
  if (textBox1.Text.Length == 1)
  ```
- Must be either of the single characters `Y` or `N`

  ```
  if (new[] { "Y", "N" }.Contains(textBox1.Text))
  ```

If you *must* have a regex, then Vivek's suggestion is good and simple:

```
    if (new Regex(@"^[YN]$").IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
```

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that if you only care about `KeyPress`, **the user can still paste some text there with the mouse right click**. I wouldn't use a `TextBox` for this, but if you really like it that way, I would use this other event instead:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = ((TextBox)sender).Text.ToUpper();
    if (text.Length > 1)
        text = text.Substring(0, 1);
    if (text != "Y" && text != "N")
        text = "";
    ((TextBox)sender).Text = text;
}
```

This way you always get an uppercase `Y` or `N` in the textbox and the user can easily change the value without having to press backspace.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making it difficult?

```
if(textBox1.Text.Equals("Y") || textBox1.Text.Equals("N"))
```

Comment: There's an extra `if(` there.

Answer (score 0):

That code is incomplete. You probably need some kind of conditional to actually execute the restriction:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
      Regex r = new Regex(@"^(Y|N){1}$");
      if (r.IsMatch(textBox1.Text)==false) {
          //do something, like popping an alert or making e.Handled = true to cancel the event.
      }
    }
```

As for the regex to use, yours should work (or you may use one of the suggestions made by other users).