# TextBox with maxvalue

Tags: c#

I want to make a `TextBox` which does not allow to enter a value above 100. Only numbers allowed, And a Numeric `TextBox` is **not** an option. This is my code for now:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) { e.Handled = true; }  // only numbers
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a binding or do you grab the number by `Text`-Property?

Comment: I don't know... It's just a textBox, with text in it which happens to be numbers so to speak.

Comment: could you explain a bit more why NumericUpAndDown is not an option? ... it does exactly what you are asking for

Comment: I know. But I'm having many troubles with them in my scenario, so if this could be done with a TextBox, I would be happy.

Comment: Code like this is always trivially defeated by just pressing Ctrl+V.  Use the Validating event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a textbox accept only digits and formats numbers with commas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163564/how-to-make-a-textbox-accept-only-digits-and-formats-numbers-with-commas)

Comment: Have a look at MaskedTextBox. It has much more properties and methods to allow control of the input. You can even make your own customized mask to control the input. http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant If you set your textBox property SchortscutEnabled to False, ctrl+V and mouse right click dont have effect.

Comment: How is preventing pasting into a text box a feature?

Comment: @HansPassant, as I said. Text box properties, SchortcutsEnabled = false. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. I found a solution:

```
int box_int = 0; Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out box_int);
if (box_int > 1050 && textBox1.Text != "") { textBox1.Text = "1050"; }
```

Comment: What it does? I tested it and you can still write whatever you like in the text box!

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to see if the parsing is successful and then compare the value to see if it is below 100.

```
int number;
if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out number))
{
  if(number <= 100) 
    {
     //in range
    }
  else
    {
     // not in range
    }
}
else
{
//invalid number
}
```

You can also use `double.TryParse` or other `TryParse` method depending on the type, they are safe to use, since they will return a `false` if the parsing fails, instead of raising an exception.

Comment: Oh Thanks! This works great =). EDIT: Ow wait... it does not... I can enter "999" for example. Just not over 3 numbers.

Comment: Is that C# code? If it isn't - I can't quite figure out what it would be in C#...

Answer (score 1):

Hello, here is my solution.

```
    private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                char c = e.KeyChar;
                if ((!char.IsDigit(c) ||
                    Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text + e.KeyChar) >= 101 ||
                    textBox.Text == "0") && c != '\b')
                    e.Handled = true;

            }
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer code only answers doesn't tend to help much.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter only numbers and use arrows keys and backspace. If you enter a number > than 100 or less than 1, when you press enter it will be cancelled. Copy and Past with button key down is disabled and also mouse right click to prevent the user to paste in the text box is disabled/handled. This should solve your problem in full.
First of all set:

```
    ShortcutsEnabled property of your text box to False
```

this will not allow mouse right click and ctrl+V for paste in your text box.
Then add the following code:

```
    //prevent letters, special chars, punctuation, symbols, white spaces
    private void txtType1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) ||
                char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar) ||
                char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) ||
                char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar))
                e.Handled = true;
        }

        {
            //allows only numbers between 1 and 100
            string value = txtType1.Text;
            if (txtType1.Text !="")

            {
                if (Int16.Parse(value) < 1 )
                {
                    txtType1.Text = ""; 
                }
                else if (Int16.Parse(value) > 100)
                {
                    txtType1.Text = "";
                }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code will not work, because on keypress, value of textbox not updated. for example textbox.text=99 and then you press 9 and on new keypress textbox.text is 99 and on keyup the value is 999